# Make UISearchBar not scrolling like in Contacts app

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to implement a UI similar to the Contacts iOS app, where you have a UISearchBar anchored at the top of the table view(if you add it as the table view header it would scroll with the content), and when you start searching the search bar takes the space of the navigation bar.

I am using the UISearchController's search bar.

Have tried to add container view on top of the table view, and programatically add the search bar to it, but the problem is that when the search bar goes to the position of the nav bar(done automatically by the UISearchController) its width is bigger than the screen...
[image]

This happens in both simulator and device.

Any (preferably non hacky) way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a `UITableViewController`, use a standard `UIViewController` and add the `searchBar`  and the `tableview` yourself.

Here is a sample code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(searchBar.frame.size.height, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    [tableView reloadData];

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:searchBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```